# Can I force a specific layout to use dark mode in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dark-theme

I have a common view that shared between so many layouts. This view already has day/night configed. 
There's a new view that will `<include>` this common layout. However, this new view will have just one state and dark mode of the common layout suits better with the rest of elements in this new view. Is there any way to force new layout to use dark mode? or force it within just `<include>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Theme Overlay. Just add the theme to your view parent.

If you are using AppCompat style:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
```

If you are using MaterialComponents style:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark"
```

Comment: app keeps giving me `InflateException`